# NameError when trying to use module that has been imported

Tags: python

I am trying to write my own shell script using Bash and Python, and I have separate modules inside of the same folder as the main shell script. The main shell script reads what modules to import from a file called `defaultmodules.txt` and then imports them. I did it in this manner, because I want any user of the shell to be able to simply modify this file instead of going into the code to change what modules they want imported. Currently, the file contains the names of three modules.

```
net
os
subprocess
```

I used this code to read the module names from the file and import them.

```
moduleList = []
with open('defaultmodules.txt', 'r') as mods:
    for line in mods:
        if "#" in line or line == ' ':
            pass
        else:
            moduleList.append(line)
            print("Importing module '{}'".format(line))
            module = line.rstrip('\n')
            print(__import__(module))
            __import__(module)
            print(module.__init__())
```

However, even after importing, after running `os.system('echo test')` which should simply print `test` to the console, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dorian/Desktop/DEBPSH/DEBPSH.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.system('echo test')
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

What in my code could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `__import__` will load the module and put it in `sys.modules`:

```
import sys

__import__('os')
'os' in sys.modules # True
```

There's no reference bound to it, so keep one around:

```
globals()[module] = __import__(module)
```

You can then use `os.system` etc...

As [kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416467/kindall) succinctly states in a comment:

> That is to say, `__import__` is a function and returns the module. If you don't give it a name, it won't have a name. So give it a name.

Comment: That is to say, `__import__` is a function and *returns* the module. If you don't give it a name, it won't have a name. So give it a name.

Comment: Could I store it in a dictionary instead of using `globals()[module]`?

Comment: @Dorian yup - `d = {}`... then `d[module] = module` then access via `d['os'].system()` but that's even more obscure than above... Be easier to just have a user edit your imports :-D

Comment: Ah, ok. I understand. It appears there's a bit more to this function than I thought. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to import like this Because `__import__` is function so, it has to be stored the return vale.

```
os = __import__('os')
```

Basically

```
pkg = __import__('pkg')
pkg = __import__('pkg.mod')
```

Answer (score 0):

`importlib.import_module(name, package=None)` is a good replace for `__import__`. Or you can use `exec 'import %s' % module`.